# Writing to the Windows File System

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to create a query that is able to write to the Windows filesystem?

I have a table with a list of jpg images that belong to a product for sale. When I delete the item from the table I also want to delete the image from disk

Answer (score 0):

MemSQL doesn't run on Windows. You can spin up Linux VM or Amazon AWS EC2 instance to try it.